# How do I re-write a URL to remove the .html extension on an Azure Static Website using the Rules Engine for Azure CDN?

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, rule-engine, azure-cdn, azure-static-website-hosting

I am wondering how I can rewrite my URL [brianmilinski.com/blog.html](https://www.brianmilinski.com/blog.html) using windows Azure default rules engine. I have a static website set up on Azure, but am having a difficult time finding actual examples and documentation on how to use the rewrite tool.  The backslash character is always required when creating the regex rules in the rules engine. The screenshot below shows where I am at with this. I am struggling to find where good documentation for this resides. Microsoft is usually very good at documentation.

[Azure Rules Engine URL Rewrite My Current Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ9Gi.png)

Comment: https://blog.lifeishao.com/2017/05/24/serving-your-static-sites-with-azure-blob-and-cdn/ -  You can refer here for example. You need a premium tier CDN for custom rule engine.

Comment: I am able to use the rules engine as you can see in the screen shot above. There isn't a way to do it through that rules engine?... your example is kind of difficult to follow that you link to on your website.